# BrokenPipeError when using Gmail API

Tags: python, pipe, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm using Gmail API to send an email with attachments in Python 3.
I'm trying the same code as google developers as shown below:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending

The problem is that when attachments are **4.2KB** or **2.6MB**, the code works **Well**; but when attachments are **3.0MB** or **9.6MB** or bigger, an **Error** occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "quickstart2.py", line 184, in <module>
    main()
  File "quickstart2.py", line 170, in main
    send_message(service, "me", message)
  File "quickstart2.py", line 147, in send_message
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 837, in execute
    method=str(self.method), body=self.body, headers=self.headers)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 176, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 163, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 175, in new_request
    redirections, connection_type)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 282, in request
    connection_type=connection_type)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1322, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1072, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 996, in _conn_request
    conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 972, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 941, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
  File "/home/yizhu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 642, in write
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

What's the problem here?

Thanks

Comment: Same issue here.  Substituting `httplib2shim` doesn't fix it for me, still the same broken pipe error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems an exception is raised at _retry_request.
I haven't encountered this error myself, but there's a thread on github discussing about the same error.
https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/issues/218

Try using httplib2shim, it seems oauth2client is still not replaced by google-auth.

Another suggestion I found was to use the MEDIA /upload option for files over 10 MB. Docs for how to use /upload: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send